# Find XML attribute "NOT equal to" in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following XML:

```
<foo>
<bar x="0"/>
<bar x="1"/>
</foo>
```

I know in advance there will be two sub-elements here, one with an x of 0, but the other with an x of I-don't-know-what. I want to select the sub-element with the attribute that DOESN'T have the value of 0. I presumed you would do that like this:

```
foo.find("bar[@x!='0']")
```

But this doesn't return anything. Based on the link below, I tried the following, but it brings up an error.

```
foo.find("bar[not(@x='0')]")
```

[Python lxml.html XPath "attribute not equal" operator not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219180/python-lxml-html-xpath-attribute-not-equal-operator-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to replace .find with .xpath() the link in your question uses xpath.

```
from lxml import etree
path=r"C:\foo.xml"
tree = etree.parse(path)

print tree.xpath('bar[not(@x="0")]')
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you!